# Asp.Net Core How to Configure Migrations type to assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, database-migration

Hello everyone my name is Taniguchi and i learning asp.net core and  I managed to create a migration but when I used the Update-Database command show me the following error: "

> Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'WebApplication1'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).

my database:

```
 public class MimicContext : DbContext
{
    public MimicContext(DbContextOptions<MimicContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Palavra> Palavras { get; set; }
}
```

my startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<MimicContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseSqlite("Data Source=Database\\Mimic.db");
        });

        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

       

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

How can i configure a migration  to the assembly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small mistake, but good learning for me after spending more than one day painful effort. I hope this will be the good learning for others too.

I have added two NuGet packages of: EntityFramework, and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore which is my mistake.

Just adding NuGet package for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore will do all the required work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled migrations in your project? If you didn't than use Enable-Migrations. I think that it could be the problem.

Comment: i used this command but showed the following erro: No context type was found in the assembly 'WebApplication1'. but i created the context  isant is the MimicContext ?

Comment: Try the full command then:
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName MyContextProjectNameHere -StartUpProjectName MyStartUpProjectNameHere

Comment: in my MyContextProjectNameHere do i type the context name  and on MyStartUpProjectNameHere   do i type the project name ?

Answer (score 0):

Before running the **update** command in PMC first enable it. For more details view this link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/#enabling-migrations)

Comment: While‌ ‌this‌ ‌link‌ ‌may‌ ‌answer‌ ‌the‌ ‌question,‌ ‌it‌ ‌is‌ ‌better‌ ‌to‌ ‌include‌ ‌the‌ ‌essential‌ ‌parts‌ ‌of‌ ‌the‌ ‌
answer‌ ‌here‌ ‌and‌ ‌provide‌ ‌the‌ ‌link‌ ‌for‌ ‌reference.‌ ‌Link-only‌ ‌answers‌ ‌can‌ ‌become‌ ‌invalid‌ ‌if‌ ‌the‌ ‌
linked‌ ‌page‌ ‌changes.